# How can I extract the data between two time in two or more log files

Tags: bash, unix, awk

I have two log files namely, Log1.log and Log2.log each containing following data.

```
Log1.log:
Apr 10 02:07:20  Data 1
May 10 04:11:09  Data 2
June 11 06:22:35  Data 3
Aug 12 09:08:07  Data 4

Log2.log
Apr 10 09:07:20  Data 1
Apr 10 10:07:10  Data 2
Jul 11 11:07:30  Data 3
Aug 18 12:50:40  Data 4
```

What command I can use to get the data between Apr 10 02:07:20 to Aug 18 12:50:40.

I have used

```
$ awk -v start=01:06:04 -v stop=01:07:16 'start <= $3 && $3 <= stop' Log1.log Log2.log
```

I have also used

```
awk -v StartTime="$StartTime" -v EndTime="$EndTime" -f script.sh Log1.log Log2.log
```

where script.sh contains,

```
BEGIN { Keep = 0;}
{
if($3 >= StartTime)
{
    keep = 1;
}
if ($3 > EndTime) 
{
    exit;
}

if(keep)
{ 
     print;
}
```

}

I am not getting the desired result. Can someone help me in improving me answer?Thanks in advance

Comment: This can be a good start: [How to filter logs easily with awk?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34311140/1983854)

Comment: re-opened the question because the key here is to sort the input before processing.

Answer (score 0):

I would first use `sort` to sort the input. Then I would use sed to extract that range:

```
LC_TIME=C sort -t' ' -k1,1M -k2,3n 1.log 2.log \
    | sed -n '/Apr 10 02:07:20/,/Aug 18 12:50:40/p'
```

Btw, it is not fully clear to me if you want to exclude or include the range borders. The above example includes them, the below example excludes them:

```
LC_TIME=C sort -t' ' -k1,1M -k2,3n 1.log 2.log \
    | sed -n  '/Apr 10 02:07:20/,/Aug 12 09:08:07/{/Apr 10 02:07:20/!{/Aug 12 09:08:07/!p}}
```

At least GNU sed allows to simplify the latter command to:

```
LC_TIME=C sort -t' ' -k1,1M -k2,3n 1.log 2.log \
    | sed -n  '/Apr 10 02:07:20/,/Aug 12 09:08:07/{//!p}'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am a beginner, still I have some doubts.May I know why `LC_TIME=C` is used?is the code is a single line or first i should execute the first line and then the sed command.?

Comment: (1) `LC_TIME=C` is required for the the (simplified) `sort -M` command. `-M` means *month sort*. To sort the months in the log file correctly we enforce an English locale (since the names a re English in the log file). When I execute the sort command for example on my German system it will not work correctly without  `LC_TIME=C`.

Comment: (2) The command is a single line. The backslash in bash (used as the last(!) character in a line) can be used to spread a single line command across multiple lines. This is just for readability.

Comment: Actually I am using GIT Bash. I am getting for `sort`should the file name to be specified before sort?

Comment: @Iniyan Thnks for the answer. How to specify the files which I am using.

Comment: @Vishwaroopa Can you elaborate? I don't get that.

Comment: I've double checked that the `-M` option is not a GNU extension. Regarless of your system it should work.

Comment: understood your code now. suppose if my endtime is Jun 10 00:00:00(which is not in the log) how can I stop it to the nearest date? that  is, May 10 04;11:09. Same for the startime. how can i start from the nearest date if the specified date is not present in the log?

Comment: Also I have one more doubt. Can I divide the result into two parts? that is, Log1 data : and Log 2 data: is that possible?

Comment: If you want that, you need to sort the files separately and process them in a loop

Comment: is there any option to subdivide my result into two parts? that is, log file1 and log file 2?

Comment: Just execute the command twice. Once for 1.log once for 2.log

Comment: if my endtime is Jun 10 00:00:00(which is not in the log) how can I stop it to the nearest date? that is, May 10 04;11:09. Same for the startime. how can i start from the nearest date if the specified date is not present in the log?Is that possible?