# Processing multiline variable with awk, printing unmodified line meeting the condition

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed, posix

I have a variable containing the content of a file with multiple lines. The variable is parsed by a multitude of commands (`awk`, `sed`,...) which act as filters and post-processors of the variable.

```
echo "$variable" | awk1 | sed1 | awk2
```

The problem is not processing itself, but the fact that I modify the line in the process, losing track of the original value of the variable. The problem is that the final `awk` does a conditional check which returns, depending on the outcome, the original variable, or not. And this is where my problem lays.

I assume it would be a good idea to create this variable with the original line after echo, but any of my attempts to inherit it in the following subshells have failed me.
The solution has to be portable (meeting POSIX standard)

Format of variable:

```
John Smith - - [21/Mar/2017:09:24:33 +0100] Physics 
Adam Miller - - [22/Feb/2019:09:24:33 +0100] Chemistry
```

I want to compare the dates in this file with a given date in `YYYYMMDDHHMMSS` format (for example 20180101151515) and if a line contains date after, I want to print the whole line.

My code so far:

```
date_after="19960101151515"
process=$(echo "$variable" |awk -F' - - ' '{print $2}' | sed "s/Jan/01/; s/Feb/02/;
    s/Mar/03/; s/Apr/04/; s/May/05/; s/Jun/06/; s/Jul/07/;
    s/Aug/08/; s/Sep/09/; s/Oct/10/; s/Nov/11/; s/Dec/12/" | awk -F'[/:\\[ ]' -v date="$date_after" '{b=$4$3$2$5$6$7; if (b > date) {print $0}}')
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question sounds interesting but we would like to see a minimal example of what you expect. The sed and awk expressions don't need to exactly the same as in your original code, but something simple such that we can see what you mean with 'condition' and can understand what the return values are. In general, it feels to mee that the entire problem can be solved with a simple awk solution. Also, this smells a bit of an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @kvantour I added an example

Comment: @lowcase_m I added an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any combination of `sed`, `awk`, `grep`, `cut`, ... can generaly be replaced with a single `awk`. This also allows you to store the original data and return it based on a condition.
You can easily see that the following `awk` does the conversion you are interested in (first awk and sed)

```
awk '{ t=$0
       match(t,"\\["); t=substr(t,RSTART+1)
       match(t," ")  ; t=substr(t,1,RSTART-1); split(t,a,"[/:]")
       day=a[1]; year=a[3]; hhmmss=a[4]a[5]a[6]; 
       month=sprintf("%02d",(match("JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec",a[2])+2)/3)
       print year month day hhmmss, t}'
```

So now you can plug in your conditional on `t` and return the original `$0` if need be:

```
awk -v d="$date_after" '
     { t=$0
       match(t,"\\["); t=substr(t,RSTART+1)
       match(t," ")  ; t=substr(t,1,RSTART-1); split(t,a,"[/:]")
       day=a[1]; year=a[3]; hhmmss=a[4]a[5]a[6]; 
       month=sprintf("%02d",(match("JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec",a[2])+2)/3)
     }
     (t > d) { print $0 }'
```

based on: [convert month from Aaa to xx in little script with awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10109974/convert-month-from-aaa-to-xx-in-little-script-with-awk/13097481#13097481)